# Cannot use instance member 'videoName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swiftui, model, video-player

I'm quite new to SwiftUI and I'm running into this problem as I'm trying to display a video using videoName from Model.
In the player = AVPlayer(...)(line 4), instead of finding the resource by the string "squats", I want to use videoName from Model. If I replace them I get the error

> Cannot use instance member 'videoName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Can anyone please help me?

Here is my code:

```swift
struct ExercisingSessionView: View {
    
    let exerciseName: String
    let videoName: String
    
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "squats", ofType: "mov")!))
    @State var isplaying = false
    @State var showcontrols = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomVideoPlayer(player: $player)
            .frame(width: 390, height: 219)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showcontrols = true
                
            }
    }
    
    struct CustomVideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        @Binding var player: AVPlayer
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
            
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player = player
            controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
            return controller
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1:

Create an initializer for your `View` that creates your `@State` initial value:

```
struct ExercisingSessionView: View {
    
    let exerciseName: String
    let videoName: String
    
    @State var player : AVPlayer
    @State var isplaying = false
    @State var showcontrols = false
    
    init(exerciseName: String, videoName: String) {
        self.exerciseName = exerciseName
        self.videoName = videoName
        self._player = State(initialValue: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoName, ofType: "mov")!)))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomVideoPlayer(player: $player)
            .frame(width: 390, height: 219)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showcontrols = true
            }
    }
}
```

The downside to this is if `ExercisingSessionView` gets initialized often (even if it doesn't get actually re-rendered to the view hierarchy), you're doing heavy lifting inside `init`, which is generally a pretty bad idea for performance.

#### Option 2:

Declare `player` as optional and load the initial value in `onAppear`:

```
struct ExercisingSessionView: View {
    
    let exerciseName: String
    let videoName: String
    
    @State var player : AVPlayer?
    @State var isplaying = false
    @State var showcontrols = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let player = player {
                CustomVideoPlayer(player: player)
                    .frame(width: 390, height: 219)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showcontrols = true
                    }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoName, ofType: "mov")!))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomVideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player: AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) {
        
    }
}
```

This avoids the issue in option 1 because `onAppear` will only be called once.

Note that here, I've made `player` inside `CustomVideoPlayer` a regular, non-binding property -- because `AVPlayer` is an class, passed by reference, there's no reason to have a `@Binding` with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass your name down to your custom view.

```swift
struct ExercisingSessionView: View {
    
    let exerciseName: String
    let videoName: String
    
    @State var isplaying = false
    @State var showcontrols = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomVideoPlayer(player: videoName)
            .frame(width: 390, height: 219)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showcontrols = true
                
            }
    }
    
    struct CustomVideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        let videoName: String
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomVideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
            
            let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoName, ofType: "mov")!))
            controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
            return controller
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is happening on this line, when you replace `squats` with `videoName`:

`@State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "squats", ofType: "mov")!))`

The reason you're getting the error is because `videoName` is not defined when you call this line of code.

To resolve this, you can set your properties in a custom `init` method that you define. Like this:

```
    let videoName: String
    @State var player: AVPlayer
    
    init(exerciseName: String, videoName: String) {
        self.exerciseName = exerciseName
        self.videoName = videoName
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: videoName, ofType: "mov")!))
    }
```

Keep in mind, you'll have to add